# How to nest these boxes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make nested boxes in CSS and place a picture (or a Flash movie) inside the whole thing. The problem is that IE at least adds a 750 x 4 sized empty space under the picture. Is there a way to get rid of that empty space?

How should I change the following code?

```html
    <div style="border:solid 4px #FFFFFF; width:768px;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px #E6E6E6;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px #E6E6E6;">
    <div>
    <img src="test.gif" width=750px; height: 138px;>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="test.gif" width=750px; height: 138px;>
```

You've got some invalid HTML on that line (the width and height parts). Try something like this:

```
<img src="test.gif" style="width:750px; height: 138px;">
```

Ofcourse, the proper way is getting rid of all inline CSS styles, by replacing them with classnames and ID's, and defining a style for classes through CSS.

Comment: IMG tag does support width/height attributes, but yes, with the ; and 'px' its still invalid.

Comment: Inline styles are bad practice, especially when the image tag supports the width and height attribute. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div style="border:solid 4px #FFFFFF; width:768px; overflow:hidden;">
<div style="border:solid 1px #E6E6E6;">
<div style="border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;">
<div style="border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;">
<div style="border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;">
<div style="border:solid 1px #E6E6E6;">
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<img src="test.gif" width=750px; height: 138px;>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your code valid:

```
<img src="test.gif" width="750" height="138" />
```

The image tag supports width and height, but doesn't need pixels just the value.

Try to use a stylesheet, inline styles are bad practice.

Comment: You're also opening 6 divs and closing 8.